# Line Integral and Residue Theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

[image]

I know applying the residue theorem to some integral gives that when you differentiate $(1+z)^{2n} $ n times and evaluate at 0 you get 2n choose n but I don't understand how the highlighted step is taken as automatic~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Apply the binomial theorem to $\left(\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}\right)^n$ and exploit

$$\oint_{|z|=1}z^m\,dz=\begin{cases}0&,m \ne -1\\\\2\pi i&,m=-1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Ahh I get the sense of it now, btw to the power of n or 2n?

Comment: You'll have powers $z^{2(k-n)-1}$.  So, the only terms with powers of $1/z$ will be when $k=n$.  This leaves the term $\binom{2n}{n}$.

Comment: Ah okay but that term is multiplied by a 2^2n , I believe, to give the residue itself..so 2^2n comes from the binomial expansion?

Comment: There is a term $\frac{1}{2^n}$ that comes from Euler's formula.

Comment: Thanks you are nice, btw how is Euler's formula related to the binomial theorem or cauchy/residue theorem here?

Comment: Euler's Formula is $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$, which yields $$\cos(x)=\frac12(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$$Thus, we see a $2$ in the denominator and this reveals $$\cos^{2n}(\theta)=\frac{1}{2^{2n}}(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})^n=\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}e^{i2(n-k)\theta}$$

Answer (score 2):

Remember that for the residue at $0$, you should only care about the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in a Laurent series of a function around $0$. The $z^{-1}$ coefficient of $$\left(\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}\right)^{2n}\frac{1}{z}$$ is equal to the free coefficient of $$\left(\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}\right)^{2n}.$$ The latter can be computed immediately by the binomial formula.

Comment: Ahh I see, btw you mean.." is equal to the free coefficient of" that term or is equal to that term itself above